# Would like to remove welcome message from frontpage

Tags: nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing the “No front page content has been created yet.” message from the front page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57258/removing-the-no-front-page-content-has-been-created-yet-message-from-the-fron)

I am using the Zen theme and don't wan't any "nodes" on my homepage. I've got menus and blocks, but not nodes as such. I don't want the "No front page content has been created yet" text to appear. What is the best way to get rid of it?

I've currently only got one template that I'm using. page.tpl.php

```
drupal_set_title(t('Welcome to @site-name', array('@site-name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'))), PASS_THROUGH);

$default_message = '<p>' . t('No front page content has been created yet.') . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a node, publish and check "promote to front page" the "No front page content" message will disappear, even if the node isn't shown at all.

See [node_page_default](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_page_default/7) for the logic there.

Alternatively, you could look into use [hook_page_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to remove the `$build['default_message']`

Comment: Thanks.
How do I promote a node to the front page by not showing the node?

Comment: You can use a different path for your front page in `Admin > Config > Site information`. For example, use a page provided by the Views or Panels module.

Comment: Will this mean that I will need to recreate the homepage?