# No front page content has been created yet in front page

Tags: 7, nodes

I have used page--front.tpl.php for creating my front page. In my footer it displays the message `No front page content has been created yet`. I have used solution specified in [Removing the "No front page content has been created yet." message from the front page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57258/removing-the-no-front-page-content-has-been-created-yet-message-from-the-fron) to hide the message

Is there another way to hide the message. Thank you