# Update module issue - version_major in update_calculate_project_update_status()

Tags: updating

I am building a site using Drupal 7.26.

I get this notice all the time:

> Notice: Undefined index: version_major in
>   update_calculate_project_update_status() (line 628 of
>   /XXX/public_html/modules/update/update.compare.inc).

Does someone knows what is the problem, and how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It was tempting to say "post in issue queue, not here". But **which module** is responsible? Now figuring this out is interesting task. +1 from me.

Comment: Figuring out the module should be easy, I used a check like `if(isset($release['version_major'})){ //output debugging info/variables }`. That let me determine the module that was having a problem. IF you need drupal debugging tools, please see my comment below for links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put:

```
if(!isset($release['version_major'])) {
    die('<pre>'.print_r($project, TRUE).'</pre>');
}
```

On line 625 of update.compare.inc then when the version_major is not set it will print out details of the problem module and die.

Once you know what module is causing the problem then remove this code again as otherwise [kittens may die](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59054/why-dont-we-hack-core).

When you know what module is causing the issue then you can raise the problem in their issue queue.

Comment: Yes, hacking core for debugging purposes, and reverting back when you are done, is perfectly acceptable when working on weird situations.

Comment: if you install the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and [devel debug log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) modules you can output to a debug log easily and inspect the giant crazy objects that drupal creates much easier, essential for debugging. Also, controlled by permissions so need to worry about anyone seeing the output except you.