# Where to write a jquery script for a registration form page which created using webform module in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript

I have created a registration form page using the webform module. The registration form page contains personal info and billing info groups with fisrtname, lastname, email, age fields and a check box saying "billing info same as personal info". Where should I write a jQuery script to put all the personal info in billing info fields when the check box is checked?

1. I have created a js `folder/check_box.js` file in the bartik theme folder which i am using
2. then made changes in `bartik.info` file as `scripts[]=js/check_box.js`
3. then added `drupal_add_js` in `template.php`
4. cleared all caches

but still I cannot execute my script which I have written for check box or the fields.

```
$("#checkbox_id").change(function() {
  if(this.checked){
    alert("checked");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is my code to check whether its working or not. Is it correct? If not please help me with the code.

Comment: Do you know for sure that your script is not running? It is possible that it is running but it doesn't work.
Do you have any javascript errors on the page? Posting your code is a good idea also, it will help other people to give the best possible answers.

Comment: I would not recommend modifying bartik directly. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59054/why-dont-we-hack-core for the reasons why. If you want to use bartik and modify it, you can either create a sub-theme (https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) and make bartik the base theme, or copy bartik to sites/all/themes and then change the name of it and then customise all you want.
Personally I would recommend creating a sub theme over copying the theme and renaming.

Comment: This sounds much more like functionality than visual design so I would say it belongs in a custom module instead of the theme but that's a bit off topic here. Once you get it working in the theme you can easily move it to a module.

Comment: $("#checkbox_id").change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                 alert("checked");
     });

})(jQuery); i wrote this code to check whether the script is working or not.is it right? @rooby

Answer (score 0):

First off, as rooby very accurately suggested in the comment section, you should not tamper with the Bartik theme directly. You have many possibilities on where to include a js script. You can read all of them in the [relevant documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/121997) in drupal.org.

The closest to what you describe is to [subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) Bartik and put all necessary js there, or even [create a small custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7).

Apart from that, jQuery in Drupal uses the noconflict mode. Try to avoid the dollar sign but rather call jQuery. Although in your particular code should be ok as it is, there may be other instances in your script using $ that would prevent it from working. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746395). Check your browser for js errors.

Last, there is no way for us to evaluate your jQuery code if it works properly or not as we do not have the produced HTML output nor the context of your provided js code.