# Pledge cannot be clicked(no link)

Tags: 7, commerce

Have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

After creating a crowdfunding reward, it appears on the event page as for example "*Pledge $10 for Test Run"*.

When I checked the source code, I found that this line should be linked with a link `<a href="/drupal/crowdfunding/pledge/2/5">` which redirects to the pledge so that the user can make the payment.

But this link is not clickable from the page. I need to go to "inspect element" in google chrome and then click on the link.

My question is, why can't I click on the link? Why doesn't it appear on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no link content so there is nothing to click on.

A link should be of the form

```
<a href="/url-of-page-being-linked-to">Link content</a>
```

In that example there would be the text "Link content" that you could click on.

For your code I would expect it should be something like this:

```
<h3><a href="/drupal/crowdfunding/pledge/2/5">Pledge RM10.00 or more</a></h3>
```

For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

To modify the pledge markup do no modify the crowd funding module. For more information on why it's a good idea not to hack modules see [Why don't we hack core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59054/why-dont-we-hack-core)

The correct way is to [override the template](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628) that prints the markup.

In this case crowdfunding-reward-options-node-view.tpl.php is the relevant template file.

So copy that template file from the tpl directory of the crowdfunding module and put it in your theme. Then clear the drupal cache and the site will start using the template file in your theme instead of the one in the module.
Then modify the markup of the template that you put in your theme to suit your needs.

Comment: how can I connect the link to the "Pledge RM10" phrase? If I need to edit the module, how can I do it? I'm a beginner, so please excuse me

Comment: I added a possible solution to my answer.

Comment: This is actually not really a drupal specific question. How a tags work is very basic fundamental HTML knowledge and if you don't have that fundamental knowledge yet I would suggest doing some learning before attempting to build or modify websites.

Comment: @rooby it should also just be mentioned that it is also possible to just use CSS, such as: #reward-options .text a { display:inline-block;width:160px; height:60px; background-image:url(some-image.jpg);}. Which, as you remarked, does not make it a Drupal related question yet again.

Comment: @J.Reynolds: Personally I don't recommend adding content in CSS like that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am aware of how to add an HTML link to a page. What I want to know is, I'm using the Drupal Crowdfunding Module. Via this module, I have the option of creating rewards. The link is created after I create a reward. I want to know if I can edit the core file of the module so that it just doesn't display the phrase seperately and the link hidden in the code

Comment: @rooby It is not content, just styling via CSS (adding a background image)

Comment: @J.Reynolds: If it is a background image that is purely cosmetic and has no content value then that is ok, however if the image is actual content then it should be an img tag and not be a background image.

Comment: @Chirath: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, where exactly in the theme folder? In the root folder of the theme I'm using, or there are folders in it called: color,css,images,templates.

Comment: If your theme has a templates folder then it will go in there.

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @rooby I edited the question, please have a look and help me

Comment: Ok, finally I got the answer! Thanks @robby for your great help. I found the node id and reward product id and created a new link below the actual phrase and linked it to the pledge page. If you guys have any other way of doing it, please comment. But anyway it works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Surround "Pledge" between the  elements, like this:

```
<a href="/yourlinkhere">Pledge</a> RM 10.00...
```