# Taxonomy drag and drop for only 2 levels

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I've created a vocabulary, I can add terms but I want to "configure" this taxonomy to add terms with only 2 levels.

I'm talking about the default table that show my vocabulary terms (drag and drop system). How can I make it set only a term and sub-terms (disable sub-sub-...-subterms)?

I've tested the select module but as long as I can add multiple hierarchic terms, the select module add them as well, so it's not the solution

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme function [`theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.admin.inc/function/theme_taxonomy_overview_terms/7) drives the taxonomy overview table you're describing. The Drupal API function [`drupal_add_tabledrag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) has an 8th parameter `$limit` that specifies the maximum depth of hierarchy. If it's set to 1, it will do what you describe.

In your theme, you can override `theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()` so the `$limit` is to 1. In order to do this.

1. Copy `theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()` to your theme's **template.php**.
2. Rename the function to `MYTHEME_taxonomy_overview_terms` in your **template.php**.
3. Alter the line `drupal_add_tabledrag('taxonomy', 'match', 'parent', 'term-parent', 'term-parent', 'term-id', FALSE);` so that the 8th parameter is 1 (i.e. change it to `drupal_add_tabledrag('taxonomy', 'match', 'parent', 'term-parent', 'term-parent', 'term-id', FALSE, 1);` )
4. Flush your theme cache to pickup the updated taxonomy overview page.

Comment: Hi Shawn and thank's for your answer, I just want to know, what if I add the limit on the "theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()" without copying it on template.php ?

Comment: I mean your answer is THE answer, and it works for me, but I'm just wondering if I didn't copy and past on template.php what would be the problem ?

Comment: You mean if you altered `theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()` directly? That runs into the problem of [hacking Drupal core](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59054/why-dont-we-hack-core). In this case, it wouldn't be a huge deal, but it's something you should avoid.